# using system() to call ln from a cpp program

Tags: c++, ln

I am trying to call system from a cpp program with the following command

```
system("ln -s -t \"targetDir[0]\" \"baseDir[0]\"");
```

Both targetDir and baseDir are QStringList. The program compiles and runs but when I execute the command i get the error ln : targetDir[0] is an invalid command. When I test by hard coding the values instead of using variables it works just fine. I can only conclude it is not escaping the string to put the value of the variables int the argument passed to ln. For the life of me I can't figure out why not.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Format the string first, either with the `std::string` append (`+`) operator, or using `std::ostringstream` (or the Qt equivalents).

Comment: Why? You can do it with a system call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confused. The [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) library function (it is *not* a command, and despite its name is *not* a [system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call), those are listed in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)) is [forking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(system_call)) a `/bin/sh -c` process which obviously don't have any idea about the variables of your C++ program (at runtime, variables don't exist; there are only locations).

BTW, using  [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) without care can be dangerous because of [code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) issues. Imagine in your (wrong) approach that the `targetDir[0]` contains something like `foo; rm -rf $HOME` ....

---

To make a symbolic link, forking a process is overkill. Just call the [symlink(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/symlink.2.html) system call (which the [ln(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ln.1.html) command will call if invoked as `ln -s`)

The Qt library offers the [QFile](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html) class with its [QFile::link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html#link) member function, or the static [QFile::link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html#link) (both will call [symlink(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/symlink.2.html))

Future (or recent) versions of C++, starting from [C++17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B17), will provide the [`std::filesystem::create_symlink` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/create_symlink) (which on Linux will call 
 [symlink(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/symlink.2.html)). It is probably inspired by [Boost filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) library.

PS. If coding for Linux or POSIX I recommend reading *[Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)* (which is freely downloadable). But if you want a source-portable Qt program restrict yourself to the generous [Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/classes.html) API. Or adopt C++17 and use its [`std::filesystem`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) thing.

Comment: Oh, nice. There's a static 2-arg version so you don't even have to instantiate the class: `QFile::link(target, link);`

Comment: Thanks very much. I ended up taking the symlink() route. I haven't programmed in about 15 years and have just started using linux.

Answer (score 1):

C++ by no means performs string interpolation.

If you are actually writing in C++, you can (considering `targetDir` is `char **` or something alike):

```
std::string command = std::string("ln -s -t \"") + targetDir[0] + "\" \"" + baseDir[0] + "\"";
system(command.c_str());
```

Comment: Don't use `strncpy`.

Comment: Wait what? Why?

Comment: Because it's a horrible function that shouldn't exist. And it's unsafe.

Comment: Could you please enlighten me then what should I use to copy C strings around?

Comment: Probably `memcpy`. (Or `std::string`, considering this is a C++ question.)

Comment: Aight, I'll just remove C part of the question.

Comment: The only difference between `strncpy` and `memcpy` is that `strncpy` will stop reading from the source pointer when it hits a `'\0'` and keep writing `'\0'` bytes: `char buf[4]; memcpy(buf, "a\0bc", 4);` produces `{ 'a', '\0', 'b', 'c' }` whereas `strncpy(buf, "a\0bc", 4);` produces `{ 'a', '\0', '\0', '\0' }`. Neither of them will create a C string if the source doesn't contain any `'\0'` within the first N bytes.

Comment: @melpomene, yes, not that I'm arguing with you though - you are mostly right, and thanks for an elaborate comments.